# TraMineR seqdplot : order states by total frequency

Tags: r, traminer

I would like to display a state distribution plot (obtained with `seqdplot`) ordered by state frequency.
For instance, with the *mvad* dataset :

```
library(TraMineR)
data(mvad)

mvad.labels <- c("employment", "further education", "higher education", "joblessness", "school", "training")
mvad.scode <- c("EM", "FE", "HE", "JL", "SC", "TR")
mvad.seq <- seqdef(mvad, 17:86, states = mvad.scode,labels = mvad.labels, xtstep = 6)

seqdplot(mvad.seq, border = NA, title = "State distribution plot")
```

[image: State distribution plot]

I'd like to have the states plotted in order of their global frequency (with the most frequent state at the bottom of the plot and least frequent at the top for instance, or in any specified order for that matter).
Is that possible with the `seqdplot` function ? 
Or do you guys know other alternatives ? (ggplot2..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TraMineR` plots retain the state order of the state sequence object. To change the order, you have to define a new state sequence object with the wanted order of the states.

You get the state frequencies with `seqmeant`. Once you have defined the order, you impose it by explicitly defining the alphabet in `seqdef`. You have also to sort accordingly short and long labels, as well as state colors.

Here is how you can do that

```
## Get state freq with seqmeant
mt <- seqmeant(mvad.seq)
## order of frequencies
ord <- order(mt, decreasing = TRUE)

## Sorted alphabet
alph.s <- rownames(mt)[ord]
## we need also to sort accordingly labels and colors
mvad.labels.s <- mvad.labels[ord]
mvad.scode.s <- mvad.scode[ord]
cpal.s <- cpal(mvad.seq)[ord]

## Define sequence object with sorted states
mvad.seq.s <- seqdef(mvad.seq, alphabet = alph.s, states = mvad.scode.s,
                   labels = mvad.labels.s, cpal = cpal.s, xtstep = 6)

seqdplot(mvad.seq.s, border = NA, main = "State distribution plot")
```

[image]